# Does the suffix in "lipolysis" and "ketosis" have the same meaning in both the words?

Tags: meaning, suffixes

*Lipolysis* and *ketosis* both end in *‑sis*.

Does that suffix have the same meaning in both the words?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. The suffix in *lipolysis* is *-lysis*, while the suffix in *ketosis* is *-osis*.

[*-lysis*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-lysis) is a 'scientific/medical suffix meaning "loosening, dissolving, dissolution," from Gk. *lysis*'.
The word [*lipolysis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipolysis) means the breakdown of lipids.

The word [*ketosis*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ketosis) comes from '*keto-* combining form of *ketone*, + *-osis*', where [*-osis*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-osis) is a 'suffix expressing state or condition, in medical terminology denoting "a state of disease," from L. *-osis*, from Gk. *-osis*'. [*Ketosis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketosis) is a disease 'characterised by elevated levels of ketone bodies in the blood'.

The connection between the two is that the process of lipolysis produces ketones, an excess of which is called ketosis, but this is not an etymological connection.

Comment: Ketosis is not necessarily a disease state. It is a natural state when carbohydrate is in short supply and fat is used for energy.

Answer (score 4):

The final *-sis* in *lipolysis* and *ketosis* comes from the Greek suffix [-σις](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%CF%83%CE%B9%CF%82#Ancient_Greek) *-sis,* which had a very general meaning: it was used to form nouns (kind of like the Latin ending *-tion*). Often, these nouns are derived from Greek verbs, as in [λύσις](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=lu%2Fsis&la=greek&can=lu%2Fsis0#Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:entry=lu/sis-contents) *lysis* "loosening" from the verb [λύω](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=lu%2Fw&la=greek&can=lu%2Fw0&prior=lu/sis#lexicon) *lyō* "unbind, unfasten." In some words, such as λέξις *[lexis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lexis),* this ending is disguised since the consonant combination /ks/ is written as the single letter ξ or x. This same general meaning has basically carried over into the English: most [words ending in sis](http://www.wordfind.com/ends-with/sis/) are nouns. Usually related adjectives end in *-tic,* but there are exceptions, such as *basic* and *dyslexic* (which is [much more common than *dyslectic*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dyslexic%2C%20dyslectic&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdyslexic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdyslectic%3B%2Cc0)).

The English suffix *[-osis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-osis#English),* according to Wiktionary, is

> From Ancient Greek -ωσις ‎(*-ōsis,* “state, abnormal condition, or
>   action”), from -όω ‎(*-óō*) stem verbs + -σις ‎(*-sis*).

In *[ketosis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ketosis),* this suffix is used on the "keto" root of *ketone* and the like.